# Retrieve non-blank column value

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have a requirement to retrieve the non-blank column values.

I have a table customers which may contain duplicates on certain columns. This table also has a column `prev_band` which is a `nullable` column.

The requirement is to alleviate duplicate rows based on `cust_id` and output only 1 record per group with `prev_band` value populated based on the following rules -

- If prev_band for all the records (in a particular group) is
  blank/Null then populate Null in the output row
- If one row has Null and the other row has a non-blank value then
  populate that non-blank value in the output row
- If both/all the rows have non-blank values then qualify the record
  from customer, whose eff_dt is the highest value out of the records
  which are lesser than the eff_dt of the contract table corresponding
  to that empid.

### customer table:

```
cust_id | eff_dt | prev_band  
10001 | 1/5/2019 | null
10001 | 1/7/2019 | High
10002 | 1/9/2018 | Low
10002 | 2/7/2019 | Medium
```

### contract table

```
cust_id | eff_dt
10001 | 1/3/2019
10002 | 1/1/2019
```

### Expected output :

```
cust_id | eff_dt | prev_band
10001 | 1/7/2019 | High
10002 | 2/7/2019 | Medium
```

For `10001`, it has one row with non-blank value and another blank/Null value in customer, hence the non-blank value should be populated.

However, for `10002`, both the records have valid values in prev_band, hence the value 'Medium' should be populated because the eff_dt value for this record in `customer` table is the highest value which is lesser than the corresponding eff_dt value in the contract table for `10002`. Also, note that the for 10002 the record with `1/9/2018` is not considered because `1/9/2018` is in the `past` compared to the corresponding record in the `contract` table.

We should only consider the records in the `customer` table which have `eff_dt` greater than the `contract` table.

Pls let me know if further clarifications required.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're only interested in cases where customer has a valid row, so inner join between the two. Customer record must be the newest effective date where the prev_band value is not null. Try something like this:

```
select co.cust_id, cu.eff_dt, cu.prev_band
from contract co
inner join customer cu
on co.cust_id = cu.cust_id
and cu.eff_dt = (select max(eff_dt)
from 
customer nc
where nc.eff_dt > co.eff_dt
and nc.cust_id = cu.cust_id
and nc.prev_band is not null
)
```

Answer (score 0):

See the [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/286bf/4). I added to more records with both `prev_band` being `NULL` to cover the first scenario you described.

```
SELECT cu.cust_id, MAX(cu.eff_dt) AS eff_dt, MAX(prev_band) AS prev_band
FROM customer AS cu
LEFT JOIN contract AS co ON cu.cust_id = co.cust_id
WHERE cu.eff_dt >= co.eff_dt
GROUP BY cu.cust_id
```